# Ler linhas especificas com PHP

Tags: php, txt

tenho o seguinte modelo de dados vindo em txt

```
3                           P0200000100000000000199                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
3                           P0300000150000000000989                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
3                           P0400000200000000000996                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
3                           P0500000300000000001002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                            
B255002104190000362538651439000000011110000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
6255002104190000362538651439ENDEREÇO   S/N                                                                                                                                       
72550021041900003625386514390120010000                                                                                                                                      
8255002104190000362538651439OUTRO NOME 
9 - LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
9- LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
9- LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
B255002104190003211038196464111111111110000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
6255002104190003211038196464ENDEREÇO                   S/N                                                                                                                                       
725500210419000321103819646401100100                                                                                                                                      
8255002104190003211038196464NOME DO CLIENTE
9 - LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
9- LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
9- LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR
```

EXPLICO:
O RESTANTE DAS LINHAS SEMPRE SAO IGUAIS AS DE CIMA SO OS DADOS NOME DO CLIENTE MUDAM
PRECISO QUE ELE SO COMEÇE A LER A PARTIR DA LETRA 'B' EM SEGUIDA PULE A LINHA E LEIA A LINHA QUE COMEÇA COM '6','7' E 8 A 9 IGNORA E FAZ NOVAMENTE A LEITURA
ALGUEM DA UMA IDEIA DE COMO POSSO FAZER ISSO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode colocar todo o arquivo em um `array` e filtrar (com `array_filter`) pelos primeiros caracteres:

```php
//os dados abaixo vem do TXT
$dadosTXT = '3                           P0200000100000000000199                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
3                           P0300000150000000000989                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
3                           P0400000200000000000996                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
3                           P0500000300000000001002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                            
B255002104190000362538651439000000011110000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
6255002104190000362538651439ENDEREÇO   S/N                                                                                                                                       
72550021041900003625386514390120010000                                                                                                                                      
8255002104190000362538651439OUTRO NOME 
9 - LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
9- LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
9- LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
B255002104190003211038196464111111111110000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
6255002104190003211038196464ENDEREÇO                   S/N                                                                                                                                       
725500210419000321103819646401100100                                                                                                                                      
8255002104190003211038196464NOME DO CLIENTE
9 - LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
9- LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
9- LINHAS QUE COMEÇA COM 9 IGNORAR '; 

   $array = explode(PHP_EOL, $dadosTXT); //aqui a string é transformada em um array de strings, como marcador o PHP_EOL (quebra de linha) como delimitador
   //abaixo, o array é filtrado, tendo como retorno apenas linhas que começam com  'B', '6', '7' e '8'
   $linhasDesejadas = array_filter($array, function($linha){
       //Para que a linha passa pelo filtro, precisa que o primeiro caractere 
      // $linha[0], seja encontrado nos caracteres 'permitidos', que no caso são aqueles acima
       return strpos('B678', $linha[0]) !== false; 
   });
   
print_r($linhasDesejadas);
```

O resultado do código acima é:

```
Array
(
    [5] => B255002104190000362538651439000000011110000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    [6] => 6255002104190000362538651439ENDEREÇO   S/N                                                                                                                                       
    [7] => 72550021041900003625386514390120010000                                                                                                                                      
    [8] => 8255002104190000362538651439OUTRO NOME 
    [12] => B255002104190003211038196464111111111110000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    [13] => 6255002104190003211038196464ENDEREÇO                   S/N                                                                                                                                       
    [14] => 725500210419000321103819646401100100                                                                                                                                      
    [15] => 8255002104190003211038196464NOME DO CLIENTE
)
```

Função [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php)
Função [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: obrigado marcos me ajudou bastante , com certeza adaptarei o seu modelo

Comment: Disponha, estamos aqui para ajudar. Peço que aceite a reposta para não ficar pendente. Abraço.